# What is AppCompat?

Tags: android

I want to use Material Design in my app, but my app should be based on Jellybean not Lollipop. So my question is:

1. I want to use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1`. Is this a possible solution for my problem?
2. I want to know more about `compileSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion`: 
   If compileSdkVersion is 20 and minSdkVersion is 18, then, if I use some material design(in Lollipop, sdk20) like fab, `cardview`. Is it fine if I run my app in jellybean device?(which is `SdkVersion 18`, same with `minSdkVersion`)?

Comment: see this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Comment: Yes to the first one, second one is not a problem when using AppCompat

Answer (score 115):

When new versions of android are published, Google will have to support the older versions of android. So AppCompat is a set of support libraries which can be used to make the apps developed with newer versions work with older versions.

For example: When you create an android project with minimum Api level 9, and target api level 21, The newer features like ActionBar, Drawer Menu (Newer in the sense that they were not present in Api 9) etc should also be supported in Api Level 10 phones. Then, you can use the appCompat library. So the android actionbar will become androidsupport actionbar/ supportFragment etc.

Comment: Does AppCompat stand for AppCompatibility?

Comment: Yes. Can say so

Comment: "So AppCompat is a set of support libraries which can be used to make the apps developed with newer versions to work with older versions." Older versions of what? The phone's being targeted? The development environment? The libraries?  I don't understand.

Comment: The phone's being targeted. Android is running on huge variety of phones. Most of them are running in old versions because the phone manufactures won't give proper platform updates to the customer. So, an app that works on your Android O device should also work in a phone that runs on Android Kitkat. Otherwise your app will not cover majority of devices. Then the developer of the app should take care of this. 

So in simple words, AppCompat is a set of libraries that provide backward compatibility.